# Try and except return value Python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

Hi this is my code i want it to return 'A' but it keeps printing none. I don't know what is the error. Thanks for helping.

```
def example(inputClass):
    try:
        obj = inputClass()
        obj.errCheck()
    except ValueError as e:
        return e


def example2():
    class test(): 
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def errCheck(test):
            raise ValueError('A')
    example(test)


def main():
    print(example2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `example2()` has no explicit `return` so it returns `None`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value of `example(test)` to the caller.

```
def example2():
    class test(): 
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def errCheck(test):
            raise ValueError('A')
    return example(test) # this line
```